# What is going on with my Wordpress Website?

Tags: wordpress, cdn

This problem started yesterday.

When the public visitor view my website, the Wordpress navigation bar will appear on top of the page as if they are a login user. They can even see the greeting message on top right corner, "Howdy, John(My name)"

The good news is, these public visitors will not be able to access the wordpress configuration page. They can only thee the top navigation bar when they view the page.

My question is, what is going on? 
Could it be a plugin?
Could it be CDN (Cloudflare) problem?
Could it be the hosting site problem? 
or could it be a hacker's deed?

Please help, I have no idea where to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably serving fully cached pages (which includes the logged-in user content) for all visitors. This means that a new visitor will get served the exact same HTML and other assets that have been served earlier for a logged-in user.

I would start by checking the Cloudflare settings and see whether there are any options for disabling the cache for certain types of visitors (e.g. validated by cookies).

Comment: Thank you @ojrask , I think your description on the fully cached pages is pretty much sum up what we are experiencing.

Comment: We have been using Cloudflare CDN for 2 months now, why is the problem only happening now?

Comment: Have you installed any caching plugins recently? Or have you received any service change notifications from your CDN?

Comment: No, we ruled out the plugins. 
Yesterday, we setup a new installation of Wordpress in out hosting site, even without any Plugins and Themes, this issue persist.
Our biggest suspect now is CDN (Cloudflare) and Hosting

Comment: Could it be that the server (e.g. Nginx, Apache...) is doing some full-page caching on its own? This could mean that the caching parameters are off (e.g. not taking cookies or something into account).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the possibility of full-page caching in Apache Server. We found the root cause!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
Apparently, the culprit is the wrong configuration in Apache Server.

One of our engineer added the snippet below into the .htaccess as a recommendation from LiteSpeed module for Wordpress. This little devil makes Apache server to do full-page caching.

```
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
CacheEnable public /
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(HEAD|GET)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(wp-admin|wp-login.php|wp-cron.php)
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:max-age=120]
</IfModule>
```

Thank you @ojrask for pointing out the possibility of full-page caching in Apache Server.

Comment: Good to hear you found the culprit! Cache is a tricky bastard in some cases. ;)